# How to create a sort function that works with lambda expressions?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have to create a sort function that works with lambda expressions. The function will be defined as a template.

```
 template <class T>
 void Sort(std::vector<T> list, int (*Compare)(T &e1, T &e2));
```

For sorting the vector I have to implement quickSort. I try to solve the problem but I got stock at a point. When I try to call the Sort function the compiler tells me that "identifier T is undefined". Also I'm not sure how I should implemet the quickSort algorithm. I don't know how I should recursively call the function.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void Sort(std::vector<T> list, int(*Compare)(T &e1, T &e2)) {
int i = list.begin(), j = list.right();
T pivot = list[(list.begin() + list.end()) / 2];
while (Compare(list[i], list[j]))
{
    while (list[i] < pivot)
        i++;
    while (list[j] > pivot)
        j--;
    if (i <= j) {
        T tmp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[j];
        list[j] = tmp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
 }
   //Here should be a recursively call
}

int main()
{

 std::vector<int> vector  = { 5,10,2,4 };
 Sort(vector, [](T &e1, T &e2) {return e1 > e2; });

}
```

Comment: Use `T` = `int` like in the vector definition.

Comment: Using `list` as a variable is pretty confusing

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T, class Compare>  // <- Predicate is a function or function-like object
void Sort(std::vector<T> list, Compare comp) // <- deduced
{
int i = list.begin(), j = list.right();
T pivot = list[(list.begin() + list.end()) / 2];
while (comp(list[i], list[j]))
{
    while (list[i] < pivot)
        i++;
    while (list[j] > pivot)
        j--;
    if (i <= j) {
        T tmp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[j];
        list[j] = tmp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
 }

}

int main()
{

 std::vector<int> vector  = { 5,10,2,4 };
 Sort(vector, [](T &e1, T &e2) {return e1 > e2; });

}
```

There is a good example here, in the standard library:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

ps: Don't do `using namespace std;` - I know teachers like to tech it but it's incredibly bad form. The global namespace is full of all kinds of garbage, depending on which operating system you are coding on and which libraries you have linked to.

Take the time to write out `std::vector<T>` etc longhand. It will cost you about 0.5 seconds in coding time and save you days of debugging hell.